# Webform/civicrm contribution page eror

Tags: webform-civicrm

Using a webfrom civi contribution page and when submitting I get an error that a recurring interval must be selected, even though i have it set to user selects.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set a default of say month? That way the user can still select but something is there in case they skip it.

Answer (score 0):

The Error message does not say none is selected. It says the option selected is not one of those options.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this only once before, when someone messed with the Recurring Frequency Units options.

- Go to CiviCRM's **Administer menu » System Settings » Option Groups**.
- Find *Recurring Frequency Units* and select **Edit Options**.

Compare the values you see to the attached screenshot.  If they aren't an exact match, that's your problem.  Set the values exactly as seen in this screenshot and the error will go away.

[image]